# Summarise + case_when with n()

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder what I am doing wrong here.

I am trying to use `case_when()` with `summarise()` to get a summary for each, depending on the number of rows for each `id`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
mock <- tibble::tribble(~id, ~name, ~year,
                1, "xy", 2022,
                1, "xyz", 2021,
                2, "aaa", NA,
                3, "xaa", 2021)

mock %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(
    condition = case_when(
      n() > 1 ~ "problem",
      .default = NA_character_
    ),
    name2 = case_when(
      n() == 1 ~ name,
      .default = NA_character_
    )
  )
#> Warning: Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in
#> dplyr 1.1.0.
#> ℹ Please use `reframe()` instead.
#> ℹ When switching from `summarise()` to `reframe()`, remember that `reframe()`
#>   always returns an ungrouped data frame and adjust accordingly.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id condition name2
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>
#> 1     1 problem   <NA> 
#> 2     1 problem   <NA> 
#> 3     2 <NA>      aaa  
#> 4     3 <NA>      xaa
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But I would just like to have :

```r
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>      id condition name2
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>
#> 2     1 problem   <NA> 
#> 3     2 <NA>      aaa  
#> 4     3 <NA>      xaa
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case_when` is used to iterate down a column and create a new vector based on the existing values in other columns. That's not what you are trying to do here. You are trying to conditionally choose a single output based on the group size, which is always a length-1 integer. Effectively, the value of `n()` gets recycled into a vector of the same length as the group size. If you want the output of `summarize` to be length one, you should use `if` and `else`, not `case_when` or `if_else`.

```r
mock %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(
    condition = if(n() > 1) 'problem' else NA_character_, 
    name2     = if(n() == 1) name else NA_character_
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id condition name2
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>
#> 1     1 problem   <NA> 
#> 2     2 <NA>      aaa  
#> 3     3 <NA>      xaa
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yea, I know, just wondering if this is a case_when bug, or I am misunderstanding something :)

Comment: @olivroy this isn't really the correct use case for `case_when`. `n()` returns a single atomic value, but `case_when` is for iterating down a column. The output you are getting is because `n()` is getting recycled into a vector the same size as the current group. This is expected behaviour. If you want to use conditional logic based on a single atomic value like `n()` that will also determine the group size, you should use `if` and `else`, not `case_when` or `if_else`

Comment: That's what I just realized. In case_when docs: Return value: A vector with the same size as the common size computed from the inputs in ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case_when` like this:

using `first()` or `[1]` will overcome the issue explained by @Allan Cameron

```
library(dplyr)

mock %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(
    condition = case_when(
      n() > 1 ~ "problem",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ),
    name2 = case_when(
      # n() == 1 ~ name[1],
      n() == 1 ~ first(name),
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ),
    .groups = 'drop'
  )


   id condition name2
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>
1     1 problem   NA   
2     2 NA        aaa  
3     3 NA        xaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
within(mock, {
  condition <- ave(name, id, FUN=\(x) switch(length(unique(x)), NA, 'problem'))
  name1 <- replace(name, !is.na(condition), NA)
  rm(name, year)
  }) |> unique()
#   id name1 condition
# 1  1  <NA>   problem
# 3  2   aaa      <NA>
# 4  3   xaa      <NA>
```

---

*Data:*

```
mock <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3), name = c("xy", "xyz", "aaa", 
"xaa"), year = c(2022, 2021, NA, 2021)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```